# How to find the first occurance of a string that begins with "COM" in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, lambda, indexof

Is there a built in way to do this or do i have to write my own loop?
I have tried the code below:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(options, ind => ind.Contains("COM"));
```

But it gives the following error: can not convert lambda to type object.
This code runs but always returns -1:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(options, options.Where(ind => ind.Contains("COM")));
```

Any help is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(options, s => s.StartsWith("COM"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.FindIndex(T):

```
string[] foo = { "FOO", "BAR", "COM", "BUZZ" };
int theIndex = Array.FindIndex(foo, s => s.StartsWith("COM"));
// returns 2
```